# Remove all accents from a specific field in my MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB but I have some issues with accents when I want to search data.

For example, If I search "Kylian Mbappe" (without accent), I want my DB to find and return "Kylian Mbappé".

Do you know if there is any way to make a request with a "accents insensitive" option ?

(the problem is not only for "é", but for all accents)

Here is how I do it now :

```
def database_players(query):
    client = MongoClient(uri)
    db = client.FootbAPPe
    players = db.players

    cursor = list(players.find(query))

    client.close()
    return cursor

def get_players_name(name):
    """
    Retrieve a list of data for the players containing the string passed in parameter in their name. (data is the same as in the 'get_player' route)
    """
    regex_pattern = re.compile(name, re.IGNORECASE)
    query = {"long_name": {"$regex": regex_pattern}}
    players = database_players(query)[:30]

get_players_name("Kylian Mbappe")
```

Or, if it's not possible, is there a way to directly update my database and remove all accents for a specific field ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out [collation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/collation/)?

Comment: One way, trades storage for performance, is to add new fields and store the non accented version of potentially accented fields in the and search on those.